# How to use like/rlike to filter out string with space on either side

Tags: sql, regex, hive, hiveql, rlike

I'm trying to write a query to find strings where there is no space besides. Which means that 'xx applexx', 'xxapple xx' and 'xx apple xx' are 
not acceptable, but 'xxapplexx' should be queried out.

I've tried

```
select a
from b
where b.c not rlike '(an apple | an apple)'
```

But the expression seem to be wrong.

More example:
let's say we have 4 records in database:

```
    Name    Data
    a    I have an appleYo
    b    I havean apple Yo
    c    I have an apple Yo
    d    I havean appleYo
```

The expected result should be:

```
    Name    Data
    d    I havean appleYo
```

Comment: Maybe  `where b.c rlike '(?<=\\s)apple|apple(?=\\s)'`? Or `where b.c not rlike '(?<!\\S)apple(?!\\S)'`

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew just trying to understand,<= means lookahead, \\s is whitespace, I'm wondering since ? indicates for one or zero, what if zero case is matched

Comment: `(?<=\\s)` is a positive lookbehind, it requires a whitespace immediately before the current location. `(?<!\\S)` is a negative lookbehind, it fails the match if there is no non-whitespace immediately to the right of the current location, ie. if there must be whitespace or end of string. Does either work for you?

Comment: Could you please explain in words what should be *matched*? I guess `I have an appleYo` mst also be matched judging by what you say.

Comment: I've tested the code, I spent some time understanding your code but now it worked perfectly. The right code is where b.c rlike '(?<=\\S)apple(?=\\S)'

Answer (score 0):

You may use

```
where b.c rlike '\\Sapple\\S'
```

Or, if you want to "exclude" the non-witespace chars from a match (this is not preferred with `rlike` scenario, rather with a replace operation)

```
where b.c rlike '(?<=\\S)apple(?=\\S)'
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/3PAUaj/1).

**Details**

- `\S` - any character other than a whitespace
- `(?<=\S)` - a positive lookbehind that requires any char but whitespace immediately before the current location
- `(?=\S)` - a positive lookahead that requires any char but whitespace immediately after the current location.